# Cabarc exe not unzipping when filepath has unicode characters

Tags: c#, unicode, unzip

I am trying to unzip a file from a source folder whose name is in Unicode(Chinese) using Cabarc.exe utility.

But the utility is not unzipping the same.

If i rename the folder to English, then it works.

Is this a known issue? Any work arounds?

Code: `Cabarc.exe -p X "C:\测试\sourcefile.zip"  "C:\ProgramData\destination"\`

Comment: This sounds like something that you should post to Cabarc's support forums rather than here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a typical non-Unicode ('ANSI') compiled app - in which case there's not really much fix possible, any character used in the command line that is not available in your locale code page will necessarily fail.

Setting your Windows locale to code page 936 ("language for non-Unicode applications" -> Chinese) would allow you to use Chinese characters, but not any other non-Chinese characters that aren't available in that code page.

The command `chcp 65001` to set your code page to UTF-8 for a particular session would in theory allow you to use all Unicode characters. Unfortunately there are a number of bugs in the implementation of code page 65001 that cause widespread breakage... I don't know if cabarc would survive it.